# Finding power set of variable.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to find the power set of variable $R$. Since power set is the set of all subsets of set $R$, in the case where I'm given $x ≤ −4$ or $x ≥ 3$, how do I find $P(R)$?

```
R = {x : x ∈ Z and either x ≤ −4 or x ≥ 3}
```

Given that it is 'or' is it possible that $R$ can have two possible elements in a set? One for $x ≤ −4$ and another for $x ≥ 3$? I'm confused.

Comment: NO; if $R = \{ x : x ∈ \mathbb Z \text { and either } x ≤ −4 \text { or } x ≥ 3 \}$ we have also $4 \in R, 5 \in R, \ldots$ and $-5 \in R, -6 \in R$, etc.

Comment: "variable R" ???